# Как изменить поле /Producer в pdf документе без сторонних библиотек

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

Есть pdf документ. Я использую следующий код, для того, чтобы его открыть и изменить значение /Producer

```
public void CorrectPdf()
{
    string path = "c:\temp\My.pdf");
    byte[] bf = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    string s = Convert.ToBase64String(bf);

    var decodeStr = Base64Decode(s);
    //Здесь будет корректировка строки
    //decodeStr.Replace(@"/Producer (HiQPdf 11.1)", "/Producer (MyMy)");
    var encodeStr= Base64Encode(decodeStr);
    var bf = Convert.FromBase64String(encodeStr);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, bf);
}

    public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
    {
        var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
    }

    public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
    {
        var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
    }
```

Не понимаю почему на выходе pdf документ с пустыми листами.

Comment: Как этот код вообще связан с полем `Producer`?

Comment: В коде в кооментарии я указа место корерктировки. Сейчас исправлю

Comment: прежде чем это поле изменить, у меня проблема не решена с кодированием и декодированием...

Comment: Совершенно непонятно, зачем байты кодируются в base64 и тут же декодируются обратно.

Comment: а как мне найти поле /Producer?

Comment: И, кстати, Replace не меняет строку, а возвращает новую.

Comment: Спасибо, это косяк

Comment: Это вариант, которым я думал открыть pdf, внести изменения и сохранить обратно

Comment: @ Alexander Petrov, смысла нет, я согласен - это уберу, но по идее - должно работать

Comment: @АлександрПузанов так pdf-это не простая структура... Нельзя так просто его открыть, внести изменения и сохранить назад. Нужно спец. либами это делать

Comment: я подумал, что если можно считать байты, а потом их опять записать  и э то рабоатет, то можно и слегка подредактировать. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f13c6cc8-12b4-4b54-acc4-8dc5878fddaf/how-to-convert-a-pdf-to-byte-array?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @АлександрПузанов ну так вы получаете Base64 строку. Это не контент самого PDF в человекочитаемом виде=> ваш Replace бесполезен.

Comment: @iluxa1810 я так понял, по этому ответу, что я моу считать pdf в байты и затем их опять записать в pdf https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f13c6cc8-12b4-4b54-acc4-8dc5878fddaf/how-to-convert-a-pdf-to-byte-array?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @АлександрПузанов По идее да, но тем не менее у вас бесполезный Replace.

Comment: Возьмите PDFSharp или iTextSharp, поменяйте, сохраните и не мучайтесь. В любом случае я не понял вашего фокуса с конвертированием массива байт документа в строку BASE64 и попытки в полученной кодированной строке что-то менять, тогда уж стоило искать модифицируемый фрагмент прямо в массиве байт - пользы было бы больше, при условии, что некоторые метаданные хранятся в структуре PDF открытым простым текстом.

Comment: @ rdorn, именно тот, что мне нужен - не в открытом

Comment: можно считать в массив байтов из pdf  и можно сохранить в pdf... у меня вопрос как как изменить поле, но без сторонних библиотек

Comment: @ rdorn это не фокус. Я считал pdf в байты, затем получил Base64 string, декодировал ее и снова попытался кодировать, после строку перевел в массив байтов и опять сохранил в PDF. НО!!! проблема с декодированием

Comment: Если доберётесь до замены, то прежде чем менять исходную подстроку, заменяемую доведите по байт длине до исходной дописав в неё пробелы в конец. В таком случае у вас не будет сдвига в документе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> И хотелось бы получить полный ответ почему я немгу pdf считать в байты, затем перевести в строку

На это ответ очень прост: PDF - бинарный формат, а не текстовый. Любой код, который вызывает `Encoding.GetString` на содержимом PDF-файла (в целом) можно смело выбрасывать. Конечно, преобразовывать в строку отдельные его поля, которые гарантированно являются текстом, можно.

Если вам нужно просто грубо заменить вхождение `/Producer (Foo)` на `/Producer (Bar)`, не учитывая структуру файла (т.е., если такая последовательность случайно встретится в содержимом файла, он будет поврежден), то можно сделать так:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    public static bool SequenceEquals(byte[] array, int position, byte[] match)
    {
        if (match.Length > (array.Length - position)) return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < match.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[position + i] != match[i])  return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static int FindSequence(byte[] arr, byte[] match, int startindex=0)
    {
        for (int i = startindex; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (SequenceEquals(arr, i, match)) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {        
        string path1 = @"C:\Test\file1.pdf";
        string path2 = @"C:\Test\file2.pdf";

        //считаем данные
        byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path1);

        //подготовим последовательности для поиска
        byte[] match_start = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("/Producer");
        byte[] match_end = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(")");

        //найдем последовательность в массиве
        int index_start = FindSequence(data, match_start);           
        int index_end = FindSequence(data, match_end, index_start + 1) + 1;
        byte[] bytes_old = new byte[index_end - index_start];
        Array.Copy(data, index_start, bytes_old, 0, bytes_old.Length);
        string s_old = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes_old);

        //подготовим новые данные
        string s_new = "/Producer (MyMy)";
        byte[] bytes_new = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s_new);
        byte[] newdata = new byte[data.Length - bytes_old.Length + bytes_new.Length];

        //запишем результат
        Array.Copy(data, newdata, index_start);
        Array.Copy(bytes_new, 0, newdata, index_start, bytes_new.Length);
        Array.Copy(data, index_end, newdata, index_start+ bytes_new.Length, data.Length - index_end);
        File.WriteAllBytes(path2, newdata);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Корректная замена должна учитывать структуру файла в соответствии с [документацией Adobe](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive/PDFReference.pdf).

Comment: Результат теста - пустой pdf документ. Такой же результат на выходе, что и раньше

Comment: @АлександрПузанов Пример документа (исходного) можете скинуть на файлообменник?

Comment: https://anonfiles.com/q9cdy49enc/Test_pdf

Comment: @АлександрПузанов Да вроде работает. Вот преобразованный файл: https://yadi.sk/i/xQHBaclIUxMwVw , у меня открывается нормально в Edge и в STDU Viewer.

Comment: да, вижу, что отработало нормально... у меня в коде косяк, скорее всего... сейчас проверю и отпишу. Спасибо

Comment: Все ок, добавлю только то, что можно изменить таким образом любой параметр

Comment: Есть один момент при отработке данного кода. При открытии документа с помощью Fine Reader и последующем закрытии - появляется сообщение "Сохранить внесенные изменения перед закрытием?". Как избежать этого?

Comment: @АлександрПузанов Не знаю. Видимо, FineReader имеет какие-то свои представления о корректности документа, которые нарушаются, если сделать такую замену. Например, какой-то индекс для поиска становится недействительным из-за вставки доп. байт, и FineReader пытается это исправить.

Comment: Что удалось мне узнать. Редактировать pdf как бинарник нельзя, т.к. нарушаются контрольные суммы и программа, что читает документ сообщает о том, что что-то нетак. Вот и выходит, что появляется данное сообщение "Сохранить изменения перед закрытием?". Причина в безопасности, что есть огромный плюс и в то же время минус, в частности, для меня. Редактирование структуры pdf возможно с помощью специальных библиотек/ программ, цена лицензий которых не мала. Поэтому, ответ, что предложен - РАБОЧИЙ, но при закрытии файла будет сообщение "Сохранить...?"

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Пожалуйста, не плюсуйте это сообщение, т. к. оно не является точным ответом на вопрос. Минусовать можно.</sub>

Рассмотрим ваш код по шагам.
Считали файл как массив байтов:

```
byte[] bf = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

Конвертировали массив байтов в base64:

```
string s = Convert.ToBase64String(bf);
```

Внутри метода `Base64Decode` тут же конвертировали эту base64-строку обратно в байты:

```
var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
```

То есть содержимое массивов `base64EncodedBytes` и `bf` одинаково. Можно смело выкидывать эти действия.

Далее массив байтов преобразуется в строку:

```
return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
```

Я не спец в PDF, однако быстрый поиск [показывает](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10656899/5045688), что внутри PDF могут быть разные кодировки. И не факт, что у вашего файла UTF-8. Поэтому вы могли получить кракозябры вместо текста.

После замены вы перегоняете строку в байты кодировки UTF-8.
Далее вы опять совершаете ненужные действия: массив байтов конвертируется в base64 и тут же обратно из base64 в массив байтов.

Как я понимаю, эти ненужные конвертации ничего не должны портить. Но они просто лишние и создают нагрузку на процессор и память.

---

Вообще, незачем читать сперва байты, а потом перекодировать их в текст в нужной кодировке. Можно это сделать сразу, вызовом одного метода:

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Тут делаем замену: `text = text.Replace`.
Записываем аналогично:

```
File.WriteAllText(path, text, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Естественно, кодировки должны совпадать при чтении и записи.

Можно попробовать брутфорс: перебрать все кодировки.

```
foreach (var encoding in Encoding.GetEncodings())
```

Их довольно много. У меня показывает 140 штук.

---

Никто больше не отвечает, так что буду отдуваться.

Почему простая строковая замена не работает? Повторю, что я не спец в PDF. Но там вполне может быть структура данных с полями определённых размеров. И когда вы делаете замену:

```
decodeStr.Replace(@"/Producer (HiQPdf 11.1)", "/Producer (MyMy)");
```

то очевидно, что длины строк не совпадают. Из-за этого весь текст сдвигается. Но это же не просто текст - это структура данных со множеством полей, где хранится разметка страниц, шрифты, изображения и многое другое. В результате сдвига эти данные сломались. В итоге вы получаете пустые листы.

Самый лучший способ решения проблемы - взять библиотеку для работы с PDF, о чём уже писали в комментариях.

Comment: так и есть, кракозябы местами есть

Comment: @АлександрПузанов - я дополнил ответ, посмотрите

Comment: Простая строковая замена работает, пробовал в notepad++, но там какая-то хитрая кодировка, пока не понял какая, даже латиница не отображается нормально, хотя в Adobe Reader показывает латиницу и количество символов совпадает. А с библиотеками может и не получиться, В PdfSharp это поле только для чтения (либо берет оригинальное из файла, либо подставляет свое собственное, смотрел в исходниках). iText не смотрел.

Comment: iText дает такую возможность за деньги

Comment: @АлександрПузанов ну [PdfSharp под лицензией MIT](https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp/blob/master/LICENSE), можно форкнуть и сделать как нравится. Просто [структура PDF](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) довольно запутанная, парсить руками, мягко говоря, не комфортно. Для себя сделал бы именно так, конкретно эту часть поправить довольно просто.

Comment: А по поводу пустого документа после модификации - читайте поток в однобайтовой кодировке (ASCII не подходит, она 7-битная) и записывайте обратно в ней же. Т.е. в процессе замены текста не должна поменяться кодировка потока иначе меняется набор байт, а вот это уже ломает весь документ. Ну и документ может быть с защитой, тогда текст открытых полей будет зашифрован открытии как текст и замена такого текста на обычный приведет к иероглифам в этих полях. Как обойти хз, глубоко в спеки не нырял, может и есть вариант расшифровать и зашифровать обратно. Ну и версий у PDF много.